# What is the Pricing Structure for CraftCMS?

Tags: pricing

Is the pricing listed on the site for the Pro & Commerce versions of CraftCMS a one time, per-site charge or a reoccurring charge (i.e. monthly, yearly)?

Comment: One license per site, not a renewal (one time purchase)

Comment: @Shift2Design Might want to post that as an answer... since that is in fact the answer. ;)

Comment: @LindseyD Fixed ;)

Answer (score 8):

One license per site, not a renewal (one time purchase)